# handle switch statement in controller mvc

Tags: php, model-view-controller, design-patterns, switch-statement

I have many switch case in my controller class.how can i reduce switch case or better handle switch case in my controller.
I had to use switch case for handling button and link.
can i use factory pattern?
please see my code structure :

```
class manageController
{
private $controller;
private $action;

public function __construct($controller,$action)
{
    $this->controller=$controller;
    $this->action=$action;
}
public function dispatch()
{  ...  }
private function indexAction()//for index.php
{  ...  }
private function managecontentAction()//for managecontent.php
{
    ...
           if(isset($_POST['delete_page'])){
             ...        
    }elseif(isset($_POST['save_page'])){
    ...
    }elseif(isset($_POST['reset_subject_menu'])){
    ...
    }elseif(isset($_POST['remove_subject_menu'])){  
    ...
    }elseif(isset($_POST['insert_subject_menu'])){
    ...
    }elseif(isset($_POST['update_subject_menu'])){
    ...
    }elseif(isset($_GET['subject_menu_id'])){
    ... 
    }elseif(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=='add-subject-menu'){
            ...     
    }elseif(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=='add-page-menu'){
    ... 
    }
    ...
    $this->render();
}
 }

 ?>
```

i have some problem in handle my `url`. for example when i enter `http://localhost/manage/managecontent` it load good ,but when i enter `http://localhost/manage/managecontent/` html load but `css` file and image don't load !
please see my code structure in `bootstrap` :

```
<?php
if(!defined('ROOT_PATH')){
define('ROOT_PATH','../');
}

require_once ROOT_PATH.'function/my_autoloader.php';

use application\controllers as controllers;

$uri=strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$actionName='';
$uriData=array();
$uriData=preg_split('/[\/\\\]/',$uri );

$actionName = (!empty($uriData[3])) ? preg_split('/[?].*/', $uriData[3] ): '' ;
$actionName =$actionName[0];

if(empty($controllerName))
die('ERROR your request page doesn\'t exist!');
else {
if(empty($actionName))
    $actionName='index';
}
switch ($controllerName) {
case 'manage':
    $controller = new Controllers\manageController($controllerName,$actionName);
    break;
default:
    die('ERROR WE DON\'T HAVE THIS ACTION!');
    exit;
    break;
 }
 // function dispatch send url to controller layer
 $controller->dispatch();
?>
```

my `.htaccess` file is :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ public/index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: To me it seems that you are doing it wrong. All those switch case actions should be actions in another controller.

Comment: I don't see *any* `switch` cases

Comment: are you using relative paths for your CSS and images?

Comment: you are wright i should say if else